# JAXB HOW TO REMOVE ns2 in JDK7

Tags: xml, namespaces, jaxb, ns2

in my code,when XmlSchema just have namespace attr,
i use JAXB tranlate object to xmlstring,i can get what i want.
the xml string like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FoodSchema xmlns="http://www.something.com/something">
    <beverage>water</beverage>
    <food>steak</food>
</FoodSchema>
```

but when I have xmlns attr ,i get xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:FoodSchema xmlns:xsi="h" xmlns:ns2="http://www.something.com/something">
    <ns2:beverage>water</ns2:beverage>
    <ns2:food>steak</ns2:food>
</ns2:FoodSchema>
```

the code:
package-info.java

```
    @XmlSchema(
        namespace="http://www.something.com/something", 
        elementFormDefault=XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = { @XmlNs(namespaceURI = "h", prefix = "xsi")})//only this make the result different


package com.test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Food.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Food {

    private String food;
    private String beverage;

    public String getFood() {
        return food;
    }

    public void setFood(String food) {
        this.food = food;
    }

    public String getBeverage() {
        return beverage;
    }

    public void setBeverage(String beverage) {
        this.beverage = beverage;
    }

}
```

Demo.java

```
package com.test;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Food.class);

        Food foodSchema = new Food();
        foodSchema.setFood("steak");
        foodSchema.setBeverage("water");

        JAXBElement<Food> element = new JAXBElement<Food> (new QName("http://www.something.com/something","FoodSchema"), Food.class, foodSchema);

        Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(element, System.out);


    }
}
```

what should i do , i can get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <FoodSchema xmlns:xsi="h" xmlns="http://www.something.com/something">
        <beverage>water</beverage>
        <food>steak</food>
    </FoodSchema>
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using the annotations in package-info.java like this:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://myOutput", xmlns = {@XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://myOutput")}, elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
```

This way I got rid of the ns2 on the root element...

Comment: Thank you, the way you provided, tested effective.

Comment: Thanks man. This saved me a lot of time. Cheers!!